# Where do the phosphate units come from when EGF units dimerize?

Tags: receptor

Upon EGF binding, EGFR units dimerize and cross-phosphorylate. The phosphate groups are transfered to intracellular c-terminal tyrosine rich regions. Where do the phosphate units come from in this cross-reaction? Is it from bound GTP units?

Answer (score 1):

In protein [phosphorylation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorylation), the phosphate group transferred from the [kinase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinase) to the substrate comes almost universally from [ATP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adenosine_triphosphate). However, there is [evidence](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19857459) of some protein kinases using GTP as their phosphate source, although they are few and far between.

Comment: I see, so it's similar to the insulin receptor.

Comment: @TMOTTM yes, and just about every other kinase out there, with the exception of CamKII, which I mentioned, and possibly some others. You can pretty safely generalize and say that the phosphate group in protein phosphorylation reactions comes from ATP.

Comment: Ok. Except for the GTP used by G-proteins.